# Check if a string contain any text

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have this string:

```
$mystring = "SIZE,DETAIL";
```

And I´m using:

```
@if (strpos($mystring, 'SIZE'))
        {{ $item->size }}
@endif
@if (strpos($mystring, 'DETAIL'))
        {{ $item->detail }}
@endif
```

But this works fine with SIZE, but not with DETAIL.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Maybe try http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php - and wich Laravel-version do you really use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.

Try this:

```
@if (strpos($mystring, 'SIZE') !== false)
    {{ $item->size }}
@endif
@if (strpos($mystring, 'DETAIL') !== false)
    {{ $item->detail }}
@endif
```

refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: by 'non-Boolean value which evaluates to false' he means 0, which happens when the string you are searching for start at position 0

Comment: This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.  refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: I just realized though that it makes no sense that it works on 'size' but it does on 'detail'. it should be vice versa :)

Comment: strpos may return either FALSE (substring absent) or 0 (substring at start of string). try          var_dump(strpos($mystring, 'SIZE'));
                              var_dump(strpos($mystring, 'DETAIL'));

Answer (score 11):

Since you're using Laravel, you can use [`str_contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-str-contains) helper:

```
@if (str_contains($mystring, 'SIZE'))
```

> The `str_contains` function determines if the given string contains the given value

Comment: For anyone using *Laravel 6.0*, note that String and Array helpers have been removed from the core framework. This means that the above will not work without installing them first. You can do that with composer: `composer require laravel/helpers ` Manual: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#helpers

Answer (score 0):

When using `strpos` you need to compare to `FALSE`. An example of your blade code would be:

```
@if (strpos($mystring, 'SIZE') !== FALSE)
        {{ $item->size }}
@endif
@if (strpos($mystring, 'DETAIL') !== FALSE)
        {{ $item->detail }}
@endif
```

However, when using Laravel, you can use `str_contains($haystack, $needles)` instead of `strpos`.